# Show recordViewForm without extra div in markup

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-recordviewform

I'd like to display a related list of records in a simple table and need to create it as a custom component due to very strict style guidelines.  I'm attempting to do this by using `force:recordViewForm` inside an iteration of recordIds and displaying them as table rows.

However, when using `force:recordViewForm`, an extra `<div>` tags gets inserted within the HTML markup and messes up the alignment for the columns in the table.  Is there any way I can fetch the data via `force:recordViewForm` and NOT have it create the outer `<div>` tag?

Below is a sample that just shows the name field in 2 columns.  This is a child component and the parent iterates through a list of Id's and passes in the `sObjectType` and `recordId` to this component when it is rendered.

component code:

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId" access="global" >
<!-- NOTE: uses recordId -->
<aura:attribute name="sObjectType" type="string" />
<aura:attribute name="showAs" type="string" description="Set to Form or Table Row -- Default is Table Row" default="Table Row" />
<aura:attribute name="editMode" type="boolean" description="Default is false" default="false" />
<aura:attribute name="fields" type="string[]" description="List of field API Names in the order in which to display them." />
<aura:attribute name="canEdit" type="boolean" />
<aura:attribute name="canDelete" type="boolean" />
<aura:attribute name="canView" type="boolean" default="true" />
<lightning:recordViewForm recordId="{!v.recordId}" objectApiName="{!v.sObjectType}" >
    <aura:if isTrue="{!v.showAs == 'Table Row'}">
            <td>
                <aura:if isTrue="{!v.editMode == true}">
                    <lightning:inputField fieldName="Name" />
                    <aura:set attribute="else">
                        <lightning:outputField fieldName="Name" variant="label-hidden" />
                    </aura:set>
                </aura:if>
            </td>
            <td>
                <aura:if isTrue="{!v.editMode == true}">
                    <lightning:inputField fieldName="Name" />
                    <aura:set attribute="else">
                        <lightning:outputField fieldName="Name" variant="label-hidden" />
                    </aura:set>
                </aura:if>
            </td>
            <td>
                <!-- action column -->
                <aura:if isTrue="{!v.canView==true}">
                    <lightning:buttonIcon iconName="utility:preview" variant="bare" />
                </aura:if>
                <aura:if isTrue="{!v.canEdit==true}">
                    <lightning:buttonIcon iconName="utility:edit_form" variant="bare" />
                </aura:if>
                <aura:if isTrue="{!v.canDelete==true}">
                    <lightning:buttonIcon iconName="utility:delete" variant="bare" />
                </aura:if>
            </td>
    </aura:if>
</lightning:recordViewForm>
</aura:component>
```

And here is the output:
[image]

And the associated HTML that is the result. Notice the extra div tag inside the `<tr>` for each record.
[image]

Comment: why not use a LWC and leverage the [UI Record API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-ui-record-api/documentation), if the base components dont' do what you'd like, this would be an alternative solution.

Comment: @glls LWC is not an option for my client's org.  Thanks.

Comment: in theory, you can also fetch the response from the api onload if you declare it on your recordviewform and use it to render -whatever-, however, you will have to hide the actual recordViewForm which is not optimal.

Comment: @glls the main reason for attempting it the way I am is so that I can take advantage of the lightning:outputField & lightning:inputField standard components.

Comment: unfortunately, you cant really modify the form itself, you would have to go full custom for that little requirement of yours =/

Comment: or you could probably try and override the CSS, but that is never a good idea for the base components